# if Grandchild of page display menu

Tags: wordpress-theming

Hoping you can point out what I'm doing wrong. I have a widget area in my sidebar which is only to display for a section of my site.

```
if(is_page(199) || $post->post_parent == '199') {
dynamic_sidebar( 'widget-area' );
}
```

What Im getting is the actual page and its children, This is good though I changed the structure of the section which created grandchildren, now the grandchildren won't display the widget area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_ancestors

Kinda bad practice to use post ID...  But that's another story :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $ancestors = get_post_ancestors( $post );

    if ( is_page( 199 ) || in_array( '199', $ancestors ) )
    {
       echo "This is My Page or one of its descendants";
    }
```